# Is there a way to auto create an article after creating user group and access level?

Tags: joomla-2.5, articles, article-manager, user-groups, access

I'm still new to Joomla so bear with me...

I have many user groups and each of their access levels. For example, I will have two user groups for each department, `Admin Manager` and `Admin`.

In the access level, I will create one as `Admin` and the user groups I will tick the `Admin Manager` and `Admin` that I just created in user group. This process repeats many times as there are lot of departments.

Then, I have to create an article based on each user access level and their user group ID.

Is there a way to auto create those article after creating user group and user access level?

Comment: First, I am not sure that creating so many usergroups would be the right approach. How many usergroups you might end needing of? Depending on your site requirements, you might be better if looking at some kind of membership extensions.    As for the article part, what is the purpose of this article?

Comment: A few more thoughts: Usually automating things can be handled by plugins. But I don't know if there is any event trigger when saving a new usergroup, so probably a plugin won't work to have an article auto-created. Generally, I would suggest to consider and plan better your site and try to find any existing extensions or develop the ones that will serve your exact goals.

Comment: Hi, thx for the reply. I tried creating a script to run auto creating usergroup menu and its article at once. I found this plugin, Content Uploader - freakedout.de, that might work but this seems only creating multiple article at once..

Comment: As for the article, inside the article is plugin content in which user can upload edit and delete files. Since each article will be using by many users, I tried to restrict them by using usergroup and access level.